# What is a Range Word™

Tags: pattern, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **range** word.
Here is a list of range and not-range words:

| RANGE | NOT RANGE |
| --- | --- |
| orb | circle |
| banjo | guitar |
| bamboo | wood |
| ear | mouth |
| easier | harder |
| megahertz | gigahertz |
| haiku | sudoku |
| Hindu | temple |

And CSV version:

```
RANGE,NOT RANGE
orb,circle
banjo,guitar
bamboo,wood
ear,mouth
easier,harder
megahertz,gigahertz
haiku,sudoku
Hindu,temple
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is a **range** word or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Range Word is a word where:

> The first and last letters are exactly 13 letters apart from each other in the English alphabet. In other words, if you apply rot-13 (a Caesar shift of 13 magnitude) to the first letter, you get the last - and vice versa.

Examples:

> - **o**r**b**, **b**anj**o**, **b**ambo**o**: B (2nd letter) <--> O (15th letter);
>  - **e**a**r**, **e**asie**r**: E (5th letter) <--> R (18th letter);
>  - **m**egahert**z**: M (13th letter) <--> Z (26th letter);
>  - **h**aik**u**, **H**ind**u**: H (8th letter) <--> U (21st letter).
>
>  In all cases, count 13 letters on (or back) from the first letter and you arrive at the last letter.

As for the name:

> **R**ang**e** itself satisfies this rule, whilst also suggesting some sort of mathematical distance by its definition.

Comment: Hi Stiv! I've joined this community by seeing this question in the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar. I wonder if you follow a particular procedure to solve such puzzles, or if the starting point in your reasoning is mostly based on experience and instinct?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Hi, and welcome :) A lot of it is experience, to be honest, but here are some key pointers: (i) Check the tags - sometimes these questions contain more than just the usual 'pattern' and 'word-property' tags, which might give you a clue (e.g. arithmetic); (ii) see if any letters appear in the left-hand list but not the right (and vice versa); (iii) check if there are any hidden sequences in the left-hand words (e.g. do they all contain a girls' name? Do they all start with a US state abbreviation?); (iv) if A=1 and Z=26, do the letters add to something interesting? Good luck! :)

Comment: Cool. Thank you @stiv for those explanations!

Answer (score 3):

A range word is

> one where the first and last letters are in exact opposite positions in the alphabet (treating it as a circle): in other words, one is the ROT13-encoded version of the other.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any way I can get push notifications on an Android mobile browser when another user adds an answer during write-up??! Ninja'd again! :)